# react createContext not working with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm trying to implement the following toast manager to my react typescript application

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-toasts-melne?from-embed=&file=/src/contexts/ToastContext.js

I've created a file called `toast-context.tsx`

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState, createContext } from 'react';

const ToastContext = createContext(null);

export default ToastContext;

export function ToastContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [toasts, setToasts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (toasts.length > 0) {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => setToasts((toasts) => toasts.slice(1)), 6000);
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }, [toasts]);

  const addToast = useCallback(
    function (toast) {
      setToasts((toasts) => [...toasts, toast]);
    },
    [setToasts],
  );

  return (
    <ToastContext.Provider value={addToast}>
      {children}
      <div style={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: '1 rem', left: '1 rem' }}>
        {toasts.map((toast) => (
          <div style={{ background: 'green', color: 'white' }} key={toast}>
            {toast}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </ToastContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

And a hook as `useToast`

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import ToastContext from '../contexts/toast-context';

export default function useToast() {
  return useContext(ToastContext);
}
```

And in my _app.tsx (This is nextjs)

```
  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">
        <ToastContextProvider>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </ToastContextProvider>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

But when i try to use the solution, it says `Uncaught TypeError: addToast is not a function`

```
export const ToastTest = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const addToast = useToast();

  function handleTextChange(event) {
    setText(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleClick() {
    addToast(text);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello Toasts!</h1>
      <div>
        <input value={text} onChange={handleTextChange} />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Show toast</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I followed everything that was in the example. In the example it works but not sure why it does not work in my code.Can someone please point out the issue?

When i click on the ''Show toast' button this is the error i'm getting

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that it is a "TypeError" but actually this is not related to typescript.  That is a JavaScript error which occurs if you try to invoke something that isn't actually a function.  For example, null is not a function and would throw this error if you tried to invoke it.

The error is most likely that you are not rendering your ToastTest component inside of your ToastContextProvider component.  Your call to useToast is probably getting the default value of "null" and throwing this error when it tries to call "null" as a function.  Make sure that your ToastContextProvider is a parent or grandparent to your ToastTest component.